# Can we overload FrameLoader class of qtwebkit like we override QNetworkAccessManager class of QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork

I'm working on QtWebkit and using QT to make HTTP requests.
I have overridden QNetworkAccessManager  class to create customize request and 
handled it in my code.

Now, I want to override FrameLoader class of QtWebkit.

Can we override it?

Comment: What are you asking? Any class with `virtual` functions allows you to override those functions... Are you talking about something other than a class?

Comment: I can't find a `FrameLoader` class in the Qt documentation.